# I can't access torproject.org with my computer - this is not a censorship problem

Tags: connection, torproject.org

I can't access the website Torproject.org from a used computer (a laptop) that I bought. I know that its not my ISP because my other machine can get to the website just fine. I have also tried my laptop from public wifi sources and work, and with different browsers  and found that I still cannot get to torproject.org.  I have found no problem with any other website so far. Torproject.org does not seem to be on any blocked list in my browsers.

I finally installed Tor on my new machine using a stick. Once it is installed I can get to .onion sites just fine, and torproject.org just fine through the Tor browser.  Just can't get to torproject.org without Tor.

Comment: Did you wipe your laptop and reinstall the OS after you got it? What OS are you using? Try resetting your DNS to your ISP’s DNS if that’s not currently the default. If you’re using Windows, can you run `nslookup torproject.org` and `traceroute torproject.org` and edit the results into your comment?

Comment: wiping the harddrive and reinstalling the OS is mandatory for a used machine **before** using it yourself!

Comment: I think your problem is off topic here. It seems to be a local problem with your system that you cannot access one particular website. Please try to consult another Stackexchange site and add more information about your system (operating system, firewalls, etc.).